# Command to navigate up one directory in speedbar?

Tags: speedbar

How does one navigate up one directory whilst in speedbar without using the mouse?

Comment: By clicking on the directory you want to navigate to?

Comment: but the cursor is often on the files.

Comment: Do you want to erase the speedbar buffer and draw a new one where the root directory is one less than the current root -- e.g. `/Users/HOME/` to `/Users/`?  Or do you want to keep the view open with the same root directory and just have the cursor jump up to a higher directory if it exists?  For example, does `speedbar-up-directory` do what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shift-U : Move the entire speedbar display up one directory.

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/speedbar/File-Key-Bindings.html#File-Key-Bindings

Comment: Thanks! Relatedly, why was this so hard to find for me? What exploratory skills necessary for becoming proficient at emacs am I missing?!

Comment: C-h a -> `apropos-command`, regexp search for commands. C-h m -> `describe-mode`.
C-h k -> `describe-key` enter keys to see what they do
C-h f -> `describe-function` Useful with something like helm-mode to give you an updating list of matching functions. It's nice when you don't quite know what the function would be called.
C-h v -> `describe variable`. `M-x profiler-start` and then do whatever it is you're interested in. `M-x profiler-report` to see what commands were run during the profile. If you see a function that looks interesting in that profile report, `M-x debug-on-entry` into it.